# PHPUnit mockery and typehinted methods

Tags: methods, phpunit, mockery, type-hinting, php-7

does anyone already tried phpunit with php7 methods type hints? I got an issue mocking class with typoe hinted method's like

```
PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of Mockery_0_Forms_Fields_TextField::getSettings() must be compatible with AbstractField::getSettings(): array in /home/n1ks2n/vagrant/$project-name/vendor/mockery/mockery/library/Mockery/Loader/EvalLoader.php(16) : eval()'d code on line 25
```

Beacuse i have methods like `public function getSettings() : string {/**code here*/}` in my code. Think that mockery doesn't yet know how to work with this. Maybe someone has a solution how to tell mocked class that this methods should return even type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i found a solution myself. The problem is about mockery vendor package version 0.9.4 or above. Just need to change "0.9.*" to "dev-master" in composer.json. This problem will be solved in the next release of mockery pckage.