# mockery with PHP 7 and return types

Tags: php, php-7.1, mockery

I'm using return type declaration and I update mockery to version 1.1 depends on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34812102/phpunit-mockery-and-typehinted-methods) but still, it's not working properly.

I have a factory with a method:

```
public function getScrapperByUrl($type):AppScrapperInterface
{
    $this->validate($type);
    switch ($type) {
        case self::ITUNES:
            return app(ITunesScrapper::class);
            break;
        case self::PLAYSTORE:
            return app(PlayStoreScrapper::class);
            break;
        default:
            throw new AppScraperException("Can't scrap info");
    }
}
```

and in tests, I'm mocking behavior of ITunesScrapper:

```
$m = m::mock(ITunesScrapper::class);
    $scrapedInfo = [
        'name' => "comico",
        'downloads' => ""
    ];
    $m->shouldReceive('getOfferAnchor')->with(m::any())->andReturn($scrapedInfo['name']);
    $m->shouldReceive('getOfferDownloads')->with(m::any())->andReturn($scrapedInfo['downloads']);
    App::instance(ITunesScrapper::class, $m);
```

and I'm getting the error like this

> TypeError: Return value of Scrappers\ScrapperFactory::getScrapperByUrl() must be an instance of Scrappers\AppScrapperInterface, instance of Mockery_2__Adgate_Components_AppstoreFetchers_Itunes_ITunesScrapper returned.

Am I doing something wrong or I need address this issue to the bug report?

Answer (score 2):

This error can be solved by using the alias prefix with a valid class name. Like the following:

```
$m = m::mock('alias:ITunesScrapper');
```

More information can be found at the official documentation http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/creating_test_doubles.html#aliasing